# Failing to connect to SSL with Charles Web Proxy and android, but only for tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, ssl, charles-proxy

We just switched all of our rest APIs to https from http yesterday. Because of this, I am currently unable to intercept rest calls in Charles from my device (which I was able to do just fine a while ago), but *only* with my unit tests.

When I run the app, I can see all of the api calls in Charles just fine (I've configured the Charles certificate on my android device). However, when I am running the unit tests from within Android Studio, I see the following in Overview for every API call:

```
No request was made. Possibly the SSL certificate was rejected.
You may need to configure your browser to trust the Charles CA SSL certificate.
```

I'm using Charles 3.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

How to use the Charles with java:

1. Export your Charles certificate 'SSL Proxying->Save Charles Root Certificate'. Save the certificate as .pem
2. Add certificate to the JVM. Modify and run the command:

`keytool -import -alias charles -file <PATH_TO_CHARLES_CERTIFICATE.pem> -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit`

P.S. `keytool` is a part of JDK, usually it belongs to $JAVA_HOME/Contents/Home/bin/